# how to fix width

Tags: canvas, facebook-apps

I have a facebook app canvas that loads a page, but why does the page display in the size 480 x 800 but not the exact size? I have canvas width selected as fixed which should show the page as 760px width.

When I look at the frame's source code it looks like

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({appId: '', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 484, height: 825 });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I mention that, replace your app with a simple HTML:

```
<div style='height:200px;width:720px;margin:0;padding:0;background:red;display:block;overflow:hidden;'>Test</div>
```

And check the canvas page size remains wider or not. If the canvas width set to 720px, may be your app HTML doesn't well styled and push the frame anyway.

Comment: It remained the same and when I check the frame source code I see the signed request sizes it to 480 x 825 why?

Comment: It seems your app called for mobile device, please check your settings on app's page.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the page that loads into the canvas is located at www.brockvillebest.com/app/index.php and if you view the source code it is kust simple asking for a given width.

Comment: Tim this code littlebit missmatched. First reach the valid HTML, then I can help you. This will help to make correct HTML http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.brockvillebest.com%2Fapp%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2